# Scapy. Failed to compile filter expression. MacOS

Tags: python, wifi, scapy, macos-catalina

I filter for Association Requests using Scapy's `sniff`:
`sniff(iface=INTERFACE, filter="type mgt subtype assoc-req", prn=assoc_req_parse, store=0)`

When I run this on my Macbook this error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "assoc_req.py", line 63, in <module>
    main()
  File "assoc_req.py", line 61, in main
    sniff(iface=INTERFACE, filter="type mgt subtype assoc-req", prn=assoc_req_parse, store=0)
  File "~/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 1036, in sniff
    sniffer._run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "~/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 906, in _run
    sniff_sockets[L2socket(type=ETH_P_ALL, iface=iface,
  File "~/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scapy/arch/bpf/supersocket.py", line 242, in __init__
    super(L2bpfListenSocket, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "~/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scapy/arch/bpf/supersocket.py", line 118, in __init__
    attach_filter(self.ins, filter, self.iface)
  File "~/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scapy/arch/bpf/core.py", line 119, in attach_filter
    bp = compile_filter(bpf_filter, iface)
  File "~/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scapy/arch/common.py", line 128, in compile_filter
    raise Scapy_Exception(
scapy.error.Scapy_Exception: Failed to compile filter expression type mgt subtype assoc-req (-1)
```

The syntax "type mgt subtype assoc-req" is BPF compatible (see man pcap-filter).
For Macbook I set `INTERFACE = "en0"`

I tried this on a Linux machine with `INTERFACE = "wlan0"` and all works as expected, Scapy does compile this filter correctly.

My best guess is that Scapy can't detect link-type for en0 to set an 802.11 filter because it treats en0 as an Ethernet 802.3 interface.

Update. When I run `sudo tcpdump -Ini en0 type mgt subtype assoc-req` it works, it filters for assoc-req without problems.

Answer (score 1):

> My best guess is that Scapy can't detect link-type for en0 to set an 802.11 filter because it treats en0 as an Ethernet 802.3 interface.

That's correct.  You will only get 802.11 headers if you capture in monitor mode; that's what the `-I` flag to tcpdump does.

On Linux, if a "wlan0" interface has been created by the usual mechanism, it captures in monitor mode by default.  macOS works differently.  (When it comes to turning monitor mode on, *everything* works differently from everything else, which is why I had to spend so much time doing different implementations of monitor mode for different OSes in libpcap.)

See page 51 of [this edition of the Scapy documentation](https://readthedocs.org/projects/scapy/downloads/pdf/latest/).